# Unattended generation of "the perfect keypair"

Tags: encryption, linux, gnupg

I'm trying to generate a "perfect keypair" akin to https://linuxich.wordpress.com/short-manual-for-a-perfect-gpg-keypair-using-gpg-v2/ but I want to do it semi-automatized, in gpg2 terms that would be unattended or batched generation. However, the generation is stuck. There seems to be enough entropy in the system, `random/entropy_avail` shows me over 3000.

Running the command gives

```
homediruser@localhost ~/.gnupg $ gpg2 --verbose --batch --generate-key --debug-level guru --debug-all  genkeycommands2.lst
gpg: reading options from '/home/homediruser/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_invalidate (/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: open '/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' desc=file_filter(fd) fd=3
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: close 'file_filter(fd)'
gpg: DBG: /home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx: close fd/handle 3
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_close (/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx) new slot created
gpg: DBG: iobuf-*.*: ioctl '/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' invalidate
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_invalidate (/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: DBG:                 did (/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: keybox '/home/homediruser/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_open (genkeycommands2.lst) not cached
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: open 'genkeycommands2.lst' desc=file_filter(fd) fd=3
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: ioctl 'file_filter(fd)' no_cache=1
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 185 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=-1 (EOF), read 0 bytes
gpg: DBG: genkeycommands2.lst: close fd/handle 3
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_close (3) real
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK Pleased to meet you, process 10484
gpg: DBG: connection to agent established
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> RESET
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION ttyname=/dev/pts/3
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION ttytype=xterm
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION lc-ctype=C
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION lc-messages=C
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- D 2.1.17
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION allow-pinentry-notify
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> OPTION agent-awareness=2.1.0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> RESET
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> GENKEY --inq-passwd
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S INQUIRE_MAXLEN 1024
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- INQUIRE KEYPARAM
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> D (genkey(rsa(nbits 4:2048)))
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> END
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- INQUIRE NEWPASSWD
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> D kljfhslfjkhsaljkhsdflgjkhsd
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> END
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 32 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 110 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 124 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 128 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen X 100 100
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 32 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 98 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 126 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS need_entropy X 128 128
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen . 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen + 0 0
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- S PROGRESS primegen X 100 100
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- ERR 67141713 No such file or directory <GPG Agent>
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
gpg: key generation failed: No such file or directory
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: close '?'
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] stop
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/32768 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The content of the file is

```
homediruser@localhost ~/.gnupg $ cat genkeycommands2.lst 
Key-Type: 1
Key-Length: 2048
Subkey-Type: 1
Subkey-Length: 2048
Name-Real: Root Superuser
Name-Email: root@handbook.westarete.com
Expire-Date: 0
Passphrase: kljfhslfjkhsaljkhsdflgjkhsd
```

And the GPG agent is running

```
homediruser@localhost ~/.gnupg $ ps aux|grep gpg
homedir+ 8577 0.1 0.0 237364 1072 ? Ss 17:58 0:01 gpg-agent --homedir /home/homediruser/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

I have no idea what may cause this or how to further debug it, please let me know if you need additional information in the comments below.